# Devise Redirect: View Page A -> Sign Up/In -> redirect back to Page A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to figure out how to get the user to be returned back to the original page after they sign up or sign in to the site through Devise.

For instance: User is viewing Listing A. User clicks "Sign Up", signs up successfully (no confirmation). But instead of being redirected back to the root, they're returned back to Listing A.

I used to do this with my homegrown authentication by storing the original URL in the session, then on successful login, redirect to the stored URL, or continue onto the default page if it is null.

Can I do the same thing with Devise, or is there a preferred way of achieving the same thing?

**THE ANSWER**

After wracking my brain for hours, then posting a SO question, it hits me almost immediately after submitting the question. Here's how I did it:

In my application controller, I sniff to see if there is a return_to params in the URL. If there is, I set that in the session.

Then, I overwrite after_sign_in_path_for in the application controller to redirect to the stored session value or root_path.

Here's (the pertinent parts of) my application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :check_for_manual_return

  def check_for_manual_return
    session[:return_to] = params[:return_to] if !params[:return_to].nil?  
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return session[:return_to] || root_path
  end   
end
```